# Was the Uber Morlock in The Time Machine actually evil?

Tags: the-time-machine-2002

He lived in the only way available to him (and an interloper human decided to question 800 thousand years of evolution which the Morlock clearly thought presumptuous) and explained very lucidly to Alexander why he could not change time. He could have simply killed him but instead offered to let him leave.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you've hit the nail on the head. The Uber-Morlock is probably best characterised as '*dispassionate*' about what he and his people have done to the Morlocks and the Eloi. He's the undisputed leader of his people and the state of affairs simply ***is what it is*** and he ain't in a mood to take criticism from an old-timey human with his old-timey morality.

Is he evil by Western, 21st century standards? Yup.
Is he evil by the standards of the time? Not in his opinion or the opinion of his peers.

> **OVERLORD:** *I'm afraid your indignation is lost here. I have no more "human" response to the Eloi then you would have to a carrot.  It's just how we live now.*
>
> **ALEXANDER:** *But this is barbaric!  Have you completely lost all sense of --*
>
> **OVERLORD:** (stops, calm) *And who are you, Alexander?  Who are you to question thousands of years of evolution?  This is the world now.  I am fact.*
>
> <sub><sup>[The Time Machine (2002): Original Script](https://sfy.ru/?script=time_machine_2002)</sup></sub>

As to the subject of Alexander himself, the Uber-Morlock shows no specific animosity towards him and his futile attempts to stir the Eloi into rebellion. He just basically wants him gone by the most expeditious route possible, finding the presence of this interloper something between a vague amusement and a mild annoyance (and more so the latter after he starts mouthing off about ethics and morality). He does *sorta* threaten him in the original script but it's quite gentle given the circumstances and more 'it's all the same to me'.

> **OVERLORD:** *Go back to where you came from. Or die here.*

Comment: Is the Aryan-looking dictator fellow with Uber in his name and a social Darwinist philosophy who thinks he's part of the master race supposed to be evil? I guess it's up to interpretation.

Comment: @Adamant - All morality is subjective. Go back (or forward) a thousand years and pretty much everything you consider to be a universal right is probably no longer a universal right.

Comment: Well if you want to argue that future Hitler is OK because people (except the Eloi, but who counts them) isn't evil because he's cool with it, that's fine. But it's a downvote from me because he's clearly evil by most modern understandings of the term, which the OP appears to be at least partly working off of (e.g. pointing to the UM letting the protagonist leave).

Comment: @Adamant - Not only is he chill about it, but so is everyone else in the world

Comment: From the script: "KALEN: They took my mother!"

Comment: @Adamant - OK, a few weirdos feel differently.

Comment: "VOX: THEY TOOK MY ENTIRE RACE!"

Comment: @Adamant - VOX's morality is that of the 21st Century. He doesn't get a vote.

Comment: "MARA: (*urgently*) Alexander, take my son away.  Take
          him back to your time.  Will you do
          that?"

Comment: @Adamant - I expect carrots are also upset about being eaten

Comment: Somehow I feel like you're ignoring the actual story, in which terrified Eloi are hunted and unwilling Morlocks controlled by psychic manipulation, to fit an unusual personal moral argument. (Killing sapient beings = killing carrots?) What, you'll see Shelob as evil but not Morlock dude?

Comment: @Adamant Shelob was evil because Tolkien specifically said she was evil.

Comment: Are the xenomorphs in the Alien universe evil?  This question can't be answered without definitively answering whether the existence of a predatory species is itself inherently evil, which is a pretty big lift philosophically.

Comment: @tbrookside - If you are asking whether a species that intentionally kills other sapient species despite having other options is evil, yes, it evidently is. Real-world predators are not "evil" because they lack the intellectual abilities to consider the merits of hunting versus not hunting, something that is evidently not the case of the Uber-Morlock.

Comment: @Adamant I don't think that follows, at all.  The existence of a tiger is not rendered evil by raising its IQ.  A tiger is morally entitled to be a tiger.  In fact, the only purpose of morality for tigers would be to teach tigers how to be good tigers *qua* tigers; learning how to be good *men* would be irrelevant to them, or outright harmful to them.  A tiger trying to seduce other tigers to adopt human morality would be an "evil" tiger.

Comment: @tbrookside - By your reasoning, which is mostly an appeal to nature and tradition, let's say that it is moral for humans to kill animals for food right now. If you are not vegetarian, you probably believe that. Then suppose that all animals (not just tigers) became as intelligent as humans. Would humans continue to be justified in killing them, simply because that is what they do "by nature"? By nature, humans defend themselves from tigers that attack them. Should we conclude that it would then be moral both for tigers to attack humans, and for humans to attack tigers that did so?

Comment: I fear that your arguments make not just for evil tigers, but suggest an evil human *qua* human.

Comment: @Adamant - I've said it before. There's no such thing as universal morality. The Spartans would consider you evil for not killing a disabled child, the ancient Romans would consider you evil for not enslaving someone who'd fallen into abject poverty, etc etc. A thousand years from now, the peoples of the world will look back at us and consider our practices to be pure evil (***"DID YOU KNOW that in the 21st Century, so-called enlighted societies forced children as young as 5 to go to school? WOULD YOU LIKE TO KNOW MORE?***".

Comment: @Adamant Yes, we should.  Human morality and tiger morality are entirely separate.  If tigers became sapient and could communicate, it is very likely that humans and tigers would negotiate some sort of mutual arrangement as a prudential matter, but I would still expect tigers to regard us as potential prey - because from the perspective of tigers, we are.  But then, I do not believe that the "naturalistic fallacy" has ever been adequately demonstrated to be a fallacy.

Answer (score 1):

### Essentially, he was.

Any definition of good and evil must ultimately be somewhat subjective.

That said, what we *can* say is that the Morlock Overlord was evil by most contemporary standards, that his actions would likely have been viewed as evil by others in the setting, and that he was probably intended as evil by the writers.

1. **Evil by contemporary standards.** As elaborated below, he is behind a system of mind control, cannibalism, and killing of sapient beings, and likely behind at least one genocide.  He doesn't have too many regrets about it, and the system is likely largely unnecessary.
2. **Evil by future standards**. *He* clearly doesn't think of himself as evil. But he's the main mastermind behind events and systems that many in the future society loathe:

   As the leader of the Morlocks, he indirectly killed Vox's people. It's safe to say Vox would see him as evil.

   > VOX: Who doesn't know the Morlocks?
   >
   > ALEXANDER: Do you know where they live?
   >
   > VOX: Oh yes... They found our knowledge useful for a time.  They used us much as your people did. Then they decided they had learned enough so they tore us up for spare parts.

   Vox's fellows probably would too, but, you know, the Overlord killed them all.

   We know that Kalan was seriously upset about his mother being taken:

   > KALEN: They took my mother!

   And that his mother *seriously* wanted her child out of that time:

   > MARA: (urgently) Alexander, take my son away. Take him back to your time. Will you do that?

   Kalen's friend didn't seem too happy with the situation either:

   > KALEN: I had a friend who came here once. 
   >             Sort of a dare.
   >
   > ALEXANDER: What happened?
   >
   > KALEN: He came back screaming... He never talked about it after that. 
   >   I don't think he even got this far.

   Since the Overlord created  the system of Morlocks killing Eloi, if these opinions are typical, I think it's fair to say they'd view him as evil. While the Morlock Overlord says that he's "breeding them [the Eloi] for submission", I think it's clear that he's got a ways to go. Nor is it obvious that "submission" is quite the same as "wanting to be eaten" or "not thinking that the Morlock Overlord is evil."

   What about the Morlocks? Surely they'd not see the Morlock Overlord as evil? Well, the Morlock Overlord and the Uber-Morlocks control the Morlocks:

   > ALEXANDER: How do you control the Morlocks?
   >
   > OVERLORD: We make them see what we wish.
   >
   > ALEXANDER: How?
   >
   > OVERLORD: As our bodies atrophied our
   >             minds... compensated.

   That mind control is necessary strongly suggests that the Morlocks are *not* happy campers. It's quite possible (likely?) that they'd view the Morlock Overlord as evil, if their perceptions were not being altered.

   We can't even be sure that the Uber-Morlocks wouldn't see him as evil, considering that he unwillingly created them, it's implied, from Eloi.

   > OVERLORD: We have lost the capacity to
   >             reproduce.  But the species must
   >             continue.
   >
   > ALEXANDER: So you take their best...

   Although the Uber-Morlock does say that she won't remember who she was before.
3. **Probably written as evil.** 
   Besides all the characteristics that a modern person would likely think of as evil, the Morlock Overlord is a eugenicist who modifies species to better suit his needs. He has a social Darwinist philosophy, and seemingly considers himself to be part of a superior race. His species (is it a species?) is called the Uber-Morlocks, Uber being a word that had a very heavy Nazi association in English speaking countries, until the car company. He also looks very Aryan:

   [image]

   This and other facts suggest that the writers were going for an obvious Nazi analogy. Since Nazis  are one of the most common and unambiguous forms of shorthand for evil in European and American films, their intent is fairly straightforward.

What about the two arguments presented in the question?

The Morlock Overlord explains quite clearly why he's letting Alexander go back. It doesn't have anything to do with mercy, but with what he just explained. You can't change history:

> OVERLORD: Go back to where you came from.  Or
>             die here. ALEXANDER: Why would you let me go back?
>
> OVERLORD: Because the past is immutable. 
>             Frozen.  Dead... And you are the
>             past.

As for "800 thousand years of evolution", there are two issues with that argument. 
First, evolution doesn't necessarily lead in the direction of increasing morality, as defined by a moral system that doesn't consider evolution to be *intrinsically* moral. Second, and less subjective, the situation with the Morlocks and the Eloi is explicitly *not* the result of evolution (contrary to the original book) but of intentional manipulation by the uber-Morlocks:

> ALEXANDER: You came underground when the world
>             was ending above.  And you evolved. 
>             Some into the Morlocks and others --
>
> OVERLORD: No, we created the Morlocks.

Comment: Ah, something very important: The Uber Morlock is not a Morlock at all, is that right? He is a character not present in Wells, so the film has to explain his appearance vs that of the actual Morlocks.

Comment: @releseabe - I do not think it is particularly *morally* important, but it is important from the perspective of worldbuilding. No, he is not a Morlock.